# Xamarin Forms how to set the cursor and focus back to an Entry without triggering or disabling the keyboard?

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-softkeyboard, cursor-position

I have a Xamarin.Forms application, I want my Entry field to re-focus or the Cursor position is set to zero without triggering the soft-keyboard after pressing Enter, I have a hardware scanner that scans barcodes and it returns automatically, so I want to refocus the same entry field programmatically without triggering the keyboard unless I tap on it?

I have seen it in a program I have, but I couldn't do it, Please help me guys, I'm new to this amazing field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jessie and everyone, I found a good easy solution even though it took me a couple of days to find it, I would like to paste it here because it might be useful to someone.

I just used

`myEntry.Text = "";`

`myEntry.SelectionLength = 1;`

you can also do it using MVVM, which is what I did

this way my barcode scanner would press Enter automatically and my `Entry` is cleared and the cursor position is set to zero automagically without the keyboard popping up, and if I needed the keyboard at anytime I can just tap on my `Entry` and it pops up again.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue about Xamarin.Forms Entry, you can follow it up here:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4555 .

But you can try the solution mentioned in above link.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Jessie, but the problem is still not fixed, but I noticed something, when loading the page the same entry is focused -after setting cursor position to zero- and that happens without the keyboard popping up, how do I replicate this behavior? I tried PushAsync() with no luck, please help

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so  that we can test on our side?